# Laptop's screen brightness momentary random changes while on battery mode

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, display, brightness

My laptop's screen brightness momentary adjusts when doings several things, like when loading a web page, when scrolling up/down, when maximizing or minimazing a window.

These changes in brightness are momentary. They last for like 0.5 seconds the screen gets brighter or darker and then they get back to normal...

This happens ONLY in battery mode... I tries to adjust some power settings but still the same issue..

Do you think that is a hardware problem ? If so i need to return the laptop cause i bought it yesterday..

I use windows 8.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Are you running Windows 8?

Comment: @Atari911 Yes i mention it

Answer (score 1):

Specify your Laptop model number.
There is a chance that your laptop may be supporting Automatic Brightness Change (which is inbuilt in most android and windows phones).

Another chance is that a battery management software is regulating the brightness according to the power used by the processor.

Comment: This is the laptop:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&tmp_geoLoc=true&product=5376628

Comment: Is there any chance to be a hardware problem ?

Comment: If you can't find what i mentioned in my answer, most probably your hardware is at fault.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to turn off the adaptive brightness feature under the power management.

---

From: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-do-i-disable-auto-brightness/e50fdfe0-d0e4-471c-8c33-92e79d3366e3

```
a) Press Windows Key + X, click on Control Panel.
b) Click on Power Options, Click on Change Plan settings under “Preferred Plans”
c) Click on “Change Advanced Power Settings”.
d) Select the Balanced Active option from the dropdown menu.
e) Expand Display, Click on Enable Adaptive Brightness.
f) select OFF for On Battery and Plugged in options
g) Press Apply and OK.
h) Restart your computer.
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was already off...